# Solution to wait data from PHP server and using ReactJS as frontend

Tags: php, reactjs, websocket, server, client

I want to make the below scenario:

> The client stay on my website **screen 1** and **wait** signal data
>   that receive from my server. After receiving the signal data, then the
>   client will be loaded to **screen 2** immediately and automically.

Is it related to Socket? Any examples that can apply to my setup? or other way to do that?

The information of my setup:

> Frontend: **ReactJS**; Backend: **PHP**

Another example:

> The client stay on my website and they can get a new notification
>   without reloading just like Stackoverflow notification.

Or client listen to a server database field when changing.

Comment: you can use polling or socket, you need to decide which one suits your use case. if you just need to poll very often, then polling will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Thanks for reply, I just saw the information that you suggested. Polling maybe work for me. And I just got a similar example that I want: The client stay on my website and they can get a new notification without reloading just like Stackoverflow notification.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks for reply, I just saw the information that you suggested. Polling maybe work for me. And I just got a similar example that I want: The client stay on my website and they can get a new notification without reloading just like Stackoverflow notification.